# Android data binding package does not exist

Tags: android, data-binding, dagger-2

I added Dagger to my project and after that it stopped compiling.

> Error: package com.example.databinding does not exist

But this package exist. I can see `.java` files in `generated` directory.

Comment: paste some code

Answer (score 1):

Dagger/Dagger2 libraries are dependency injection libraries. Very first time the context initialization has to happen so you faced the mentioned issue.

This is tricky in Android to solve.

```
In Windows > Android Studio > Go to terminal > gradlew assemble

In Mac OS > Android Studio > Go to terminal > ./gradlew assemble
```

After trying the above command first time. Run your application it works fine for you.

For Reference :

[image]